# Have server backend tell iOS app to update data

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

I currently have an iOS app that runs a thread (via `NSTimer`) that polls the backend ruby on rails server every 10 seconds to update a `UITableView`. The reason for this is that the tableview is meant to be open at all times on an iPad so that it can reflect changes in the server data.

My question is - is there a better way to do this? Can I use Apple Push Notification system to tell my app to update it's data from the server without showing the user a notification? (I have done so in the past with Android GCM to tell an app to update without showing a notification but I'm not sure that Apple allows this) If so, how?

Is there another solution to notify my iOS app to update data on a sever change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS7, you can send silent oush messages to your application just like Android GCM. All you need to do is send the following key-value pair along with your payload:

```
aps =     {
    "content-available" = 1;
};
```

By doing this, the push message won't be displayed in a banner or alert and you can update your tableview when you receive the message in your app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { 
    // update your application
}
```

Comment: What happens if the push notification does not get delivered though ? APNS does not guarantee delivery does it ?

Comment: No it doesn't. If you want  you can consider implementing a handshake mechanism. When you receive data on your device, you send acknowledgement to your server and the server will re-send the information if it does not receive the acknowledgement.

Comment: I wonder what is the usual approach for this kind of a problem ? I imagine it is quite common ? Is the handshake mechanism a straightforward solution to that ? Can you point me to the right direction ? Thanks !

Comment: Normally what I do in my apps is that I rely on APNS only since occurrence of a push notification not getting delivered is very rare (in fact I have never seen this happened before). But if your data is very critical and you have to make sure that it has delivered to you device, you can choose to go for a handshake mechanism. You can also consider using web sockets but it is comparatively more complex than push service.

Answer (score 0):

You can deliver push notifications without an alert payload.

Whether the notification has an alert or not, if your app is running in the foreground then the push notification is always delivered to your app delegate for processing - so if your iPad is dedicated to running your app, it probably wouldn't display the alert if there was one anyway.